# CSS: Extend an image

Tags: css

I have an image that looks like this: [image: My image]

Is it possible to extend this image (perhaps inside a div) so that it would look something like this:  [image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a div of the same color using the CSS `background-color` property (I believe the hex should be ~`#999`). Then, position the image as a `background-image` within the div using the `background-position: right` property.

**HTML**

```
<div class="arrow">Home</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
#arrow {
    background-color: #999;
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDCz4.png');
    background-position: right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    /* sets div dimensions/text styles */
    height: 24px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 24px;
    float: left;

    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 30px; /* slightly longer to account for background image /*
}
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fbBsz/14/

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me perfectly, however, I would like to set the width and the height of the div dynamically since I will be putting random texts inside it.

Comment: I updated my answer. Just use `float: left;` on `div.arrow` and then add padding to the left and right. You might want to make the padding a bit longer on the right to account for the arrow image.

Comment: Awesome! Why didn't I think of that. Simple, yet genius. Thank you!

Comment: Just did! Also, if my image consisted of a gradient background instead of a plain color, would your implementation work?

Comment: Yes it should, although you might need to tweak the div background color accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Get a vertical slice of the gray part of very top left of the arrow with having width:1px. Take that one px slice image and repeat it on -x.

Here is something you can [practice with](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-image_gradient2)

Since your image does not have a gradient, you have a better chance of matching the color(s) you want with just using background color.

Comment: This is what I'm actually thinking however, I have no idea how to do it. Code sample perhaps?

Comment: Did you look at the link? Using the background image and using repeat -x.

Answer (score 1):

you can set it as a background to a div

```
#elem {
display:block;
width:200px;
height:20x;
background: url(/filepath/to/image.gif) right top no-repeat #ccc;
}
```

Just make sure the background color is the same as the dark grey on the gif

Comment: Anyway how to set the width and the height dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible in CSS. You must set the width of the containing element, set the background image's url and set the x-position to right and set the repeat to no-repeat. Then set the background color to the same as the button's foreground color. If the button foreground is a pattern, you will have to use another image as the background.

Comment: Why are you saying it's not possible in CSS (it is), and then explaining how to do it?

Comment: I'm explaining an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

No, not with that image at least :-)

Looks like you could make use the "sliding doors" technique – see http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/ for a good article about it

Comment: Yes, it's quite doable. jsbin.com/ezisef/

Comment: That works just because the sample image happens to be flat and non-transparent (of course if that's the _actual_ image, then relying on element background is probably ok)